# How is the word 'possible' used in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

"My job is important because it makes the best use of nature **possible**."

I'm not sure how the word 'possible' is used in this sentence.
I've looked up the dictionaries and thought of possible usages.
First, I guess it could be a way used after adjectives **to emphasize that something is the best, worst, and so on** as the sentence "It was the best **possible** surprise anyone could have given me."
Otherwise, it could be used to modify the word 'nature' as *post-modification*.
It's quite confusing. I would appreciate if someone answers this question. Thank you.

Comment: In *"My job is important because it makes the best use of nature possible."* "possible" is a post-positional adjective modifying "use" = "My job is important because it makes the best use of nature **that is** possible." = *"... the best possible use of nature."*

Comment: @Greybeard Probably the default sense here, but the reading 'My job is important because it makes possible the best use of nature' is another possibility.

Comment: The default sense would be clearer if it were rewritten "…the best possible use of nature".

Comment: It could be parsed as a [Postpositive adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective) or a [reduced object passive relative clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_relative_clause).

Comment: @Stuart F ... for one reading, or as a resultative construction (makes X possible).

Comment: So the answer to the OQ is "The word _possible_ is used in an ambiguous way in this sentence."

Comment: @JohnLawler, is your comment intended to say something different from what is already in the answer?

Comment: @jsw29 - No, I don't think I read the first sentence of your response. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence is syntactically ambiguous. It could be interpreted as a somewhat unusual variant of:

> My job is important because it makes the best possible use of nature.

In other words, the idea may be that, out of the many ways in which nature could be used, the way in which it is used in my job is the best one. On that reading, the meaning of the sentence would not change significantly if *possible* were omitted; it functions principally as an emphasising device.

Alternatively, the sentence could be interpreted as an equivalent of:

> My job is important because it makes it possible to use nature in the best way.

On that reading, the sentence would not, strictly speaking, say (although it may conversationally implicate) that nature is actually used in the best way in my job; the sentence wold say only that in my job the possibility of such use is created, which possibility may or may not be actualised later. If the sentence is interpreted in this way, then *possible* is essential to its overall meaning.

Comment: This is where you (or I, at least) feel the absence of the nominative/accusative distinction in English. "That makes him happy" could use the nominative form of "happy", and "makes it possible" likewise. "Makes the best possible use" would have "possible" and "use" in the accusative. "Call me a taxi." "OK, you're a taxi." If we just used "taxi" in the accusative" when we meant "Call a taxi for me" and the nominative when we meant "Say the I'm a taxi", then there would be no ambiguity.